# jQuery .find() doesn't return data in IE but does in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I helped a friend out by doing a little web work for him. Part of what he needed was an easy way to change a couple pieces of text on his site. Rather than having him edit the HTML I decided to provide an XML file with the messages in it and I used jQuery to pull them out of the file and insert them into the page.

It works great... In Firefox and Chrome, not so great in IE7. I was hoping one of you could tell me why. I did a fair but of googling but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<messages>
  <message type="HeaderMessage">
    This message is put up in the header area.
  </message>
  <message type="FooterMessage">
    This message is put in the lower left cell.
  </message>
</messages>
```

And here's my jQuery call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('messages.xml', function(d) {
      //I have confirmed that it gets to here in IE
      //and it has the xml loaded.
      //alert(d); gives me a message box with the xml text in it
      //alert($(d).find('message')); gives me "[object Object]"
      //alert($(d).find('message')[0]); gives me "undefined"
      //alert($(d).find('message').Length); gives me "undefined"
      $(d).find('message').each(function() {
        //But it never gets to here in IE
        var $msg = $(this);
        var type = $msg.attr("type");
        var message = $msg.text();
        switch (type) {
        case "HeaderMessage":
          $("#HeaderMessageDiv").html(message);
          break;
        case "FooterMessage":
          $("#footermessagecell").html(message);
          break;
          default:
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Is there something I need to do differently in IE? Based on the message box with [object Object] I'm assumed that .find was working in IE but since I can't index into the array with [0] or check it's Length I'm guessing that means .find isn't returning any results.  Any reason why that would work perfectly in Firefox and Chrome but fail in IE?

I'm a total newbie with jQuery so I hope I haven't just done something stupid. That code above was scraped out of a forum and modified to suit my needs.  Since jQuery is cross-platform I figured I wouldn't have to deal with this mess.

Edit: I've found that if I load the page in Visual Studio 2008 and run it then it will work in IE.  So it turns out it always works when run through the development web server.  Now I'm thinking IE just doesn't like doing .find in XML loaded off of my local drive so maybe when this is on an actual web server it will work OK.

I have confirmed that it works fine when browsed from a web server.  Must be a peculiarity with IE.  I'm guessing it's because the web server sets the mime type for the xml data file transfer and without that IE doesn't parse the xml correctly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the content type of the response. If you get messages.xml as the wrong mime type, Internet Explorer won't parse it as XML.

To check the content type, you need access to the XMLHttpRequest object. The normal success callback doesn't pass it as a parameter, so you need to add a generic ajaxComplete or ajaxSuccess event handler. The second parameter for those events is the XMLHttpRequest object. You can call the getResponseHeader method on it to get the content type.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, x) {
    alert(x.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
});
```

Unfortunately there's no way that I know of in Internet Explorer to override what the server sends, so if it's wrong you need to change the server to send "text/xml" for the content type.

Some browsers have a `overrideMimeType` method that you can call before `send` to force it to use "text/xml", but Internet Explorer doesn't support that as far as I know.

Comment: How do I check that in a call like I have above?  How would I set it to the right thing in jquery?

Comment: This is a crazy good answer.  Its a real shortcoming for jQuery to not handle this properly

Comment: For anyone new to this make sure to check out the answer from bobobobo below for some references and a very good workaround.

Answer (score 19):

Since IE's problem is its xml parser chokes on xml files that are not passed down using the correct "text/xml" header, you can include a bit of code in the **Ajax complete** event:

```
    complete: function( xhr, status )
    {
      alert( "COMPLETE.  You got:\n\n" + xhr.responseText ) ;
      if( status == 'parsererror' )
      {
        alert( "There was a PARSERERROR.  Luckily, we know how to fix that.\n\n" +
               "The complete server response text was " + xhr.responseText ) ;

        xmlDoc = null;

        // Create the xml document from the responseText string.
        // This uses the w3schools method.
        // see also
        if( window.DOMParser )
        {
          parser=new DOMParser();
          xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString( xhr.responseText,"text/xml" ) ;
        }
        else // Internet Explorer
        {
          xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" ) ;
          xmlDoc.async = "false" ;
          xmlDoc.loadXML( xhr.responseText ) ;
        }

        $( '#response' ).append( '<p>complete event/xmlDoc: ' + xmlDoc + '</p>' ) ;
        $( '#response' ).append( '<p>complete event/status: ' + status + '</p>' ) ;

        processXMLDoc( xmlDoc ) ;
      }
    },
```

### here's a more complete example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Reading XML with jQuery</title>
<style>
#response
{
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function processXMLDoc( xmlDoc )
{
  var heading = $(xmlDoc).find('heading').text() ;
  $( '#response' ).append( '<h1>' + heading + '</h1>' ) ;

  var bodyText = $(xmlDoc).find('body').text() ;
  $( '#response' ).append( '<p>' + bodyText + '</p>' ) ;
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
  jQuery.ajax({

    type: "GET",

    url: "a.xml",  // ! watch out for same
    // origin type problems

    dataType: "xml", // 'xml' passes it through the browser's xml parser

    success: function( xmlDoc, status )
    {
      // The SUCCESS EVENT means that the xml document
      // came down from the server AND got parsed successfully
      // using the browser's own xml parsing caps.

      processXMLDoc( xmlDoc );

      // IE gets very upset when
      // the mime-type of the document that
      // gets passed down isn't text/xml.

      // If you are missing the text/xml header
      // apparently the xml parse fails,
      // and in IE you don't get to execute this function AT ALL.

    },
    complete: function( xhr, status )
    {
      alert( "COMPLETE.  You got:\n\n" + xhr.responseText ) ;
      if( status == 'parsererror' )
      {
        alert( "There was a PARSERERROR.  Luckily, we know how to fix that.\n\n" +
               "The complete server response text was " + xhr.responseText ) ;

        xmlDoc = null;

        // Create the xml document from the responseText string.
        // This uses the w3schools method.
        // see also
        if( window.DOMParser )
        {
          parser=new DOMParser();
          xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString( xhr.responseText,"text/xml" ) ;
        }
        else // Internet Explorer
        {
          xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" ) ;
          xmlDoc.async = "false" ;
          xmlDoc.loadXML( xhr.responseText ) ;
        }

        $( '#response' ).append( '<p>complete event/xmlDoc: ' + xmlDoc + '</p>' ) ;
        $( '#response' ).append( '<p>complete event/status: ' + status + '</p>' ) ;

        processXMLDoc( xmlDoc ) ;
      }
    },
    error: function( xhr, status, error )
    {
      alert( 'ERROR: ' + status ) ;
      alert( xhr.responseText ) ;
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <h1><a href="http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/">Reading XML with jQuery</a></h1>
    <p>
      <a href="http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options">#1 jQuery.ajax ref</a>
    </p>

  </div>

  <p>Server says:</p>
  <pre id="response">

  </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

### contents of a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

It extends [this example](http://marcgrabanski.com/article/jquery-makes-parsing-xml-easy).

Comment: jquery 1.5 now included a function parseXML which is doing this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 6):

The dataType :"xml" does not fix this issue in IE8, rather it throughs a "TypeError" expection.

Quick & Dirty fix, is to wrap the xml response in a html element, like div:

```
$("<div>" + xml + "</div>").find("something");
```

(works in all browsers)

Answer (score 5):

You may find that if you pass the data type into your get call, it may parse as XML properly. IE's quirks could stop jQuery autodetecting it as XML, resulting in the wrong data type being passed to the callback function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('messages.xml', function(d) {
          //I have confirmed that it gets to here in IE
          //and it has the xml loaded.
          //alert(d); gives me a message box with the xml text in it
          //alert($(d).find('message')); gives me "[object Object]"
          //alert($(d).find('message')[0]); gives me "undefined"
          //alert($(d).find('message').Length); gives me "undefined"
          $(d).find('message').each(function() {
            //But it never gets to here in IE
            var $msg = $(this);
            var type = $msg.attr("type");
            var message = $msg.text();
            switch (type) {
            case "HeaderMessage":
              $("#HeaderMessageDiv").html(message);
              break;
            case "FooterMessage":
              $("#footermessagecell").html(message);
              break;
              default:
            }
          });
        }, "xml");
      });
</script>
```

EDIT:

I have actually just experienced .find() not working for a project in any browser but I was able to use .filter() instead. It's annoying that I had to resort to this but if it works....

```
$(d).filter('message').each(......);
```

Comment: Adding "xml" didn't work, neither did filter.  At this point I guess I have to chalk it up to a peculiarity in IE.  As long as it works on the server I can live with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
<a>
<messages>
  <message type="HeaderMessage">
    This message is put up in the header area.
  </message>
  <message type="FooterMessage">
    This message is put in the lower left cell.
  </message>
</messages>
</a>
```

and use find(). It works for IE8 and for firefox v.3.6.3

Answer (score 3):

I also had an same problem but I had fixed the IE jQuery XML .find() issue using below code.

Note: Use .text() instead of .html().

```
jQuery.ajax({
 type: "GET",
        url: "textxml.php",
        success: function(msg){             
            data = parseXml(msg);
            //alert(data);
            var final_price = jQuery(data).find("price1").text();
            alert(final_price); 
            }
    });     

function parseXml(xml) {
     if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
        var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); 
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
        xml = xmlDoc;
    }   
    return xml;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes IE reads line breaks as extra nodes. Try removing the extra white space up to the tags, or try encasing it as CDATA.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when I was retrieving data from an XML document. After googling a lot on the Internet, I came up finding this website but with no proper answer to the issue. But one answer helped me solving the problem though:

"Since IE's problem is its xml parser chokes on xml files that are not passed down using the correct "text/xml" header, you can include a bit of code in the Ajax complete event:"

I have identified two problems with IE when making the $.ajax(...) and $.get(...) calls:

1. The *xml* parameter value must be in upper case ('XML' not 'xml') for both calls - $.ajax(..., dataType: "XML") and *$.get(xmlDataFilePath, function(d){...}, "xml")*
2. When the ajax call succeeds, **the xml argument of the callback function is actually a *string* not an XML DOM object**

The second issue is solved this way:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax(
    { 
        type: "GET",
        url: "messages.xml", 
        dataType: "XML", /* this parameter MUST BE UPPER CASE for it to work in IE */
        success: function(xml)
        { 
            processXmlDoc( createXmlDOMObject ( xml ) );
        }, /* success: */
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
        { 
            alert(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        } /* error: */
    });/* $.ajax */

    function createXmlDOMObject(xmlString)
    {
        var xmlDoc = null;

        if( ! window.DOMParser )
        {
            // the xml string cannot be directly manipulated by browsers 
            // such as Internet Explorer because they rely on an external 
            // DOM parsing framework...
            // create and load an XML document object through the DOM 
            // ActiveXObject that it can deal with
            xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.loadXML( xmlString );
        }
        else
        {
            // the current browser is capable of creating its own DOM parser
            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString( xmlString, "text/xml" ) ;
        }

        return xmlDoc;
    }

    function processXmlDoc(xmlDoc)
    {
        // write here your XML processing logic for the document object...
    } 
}); // $(document).ready
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the following content.

```
dataType :"text/xml",
```

to

```
dataType :"xml",
```

No need to change the find().

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'messages.xml',
  success: function(data){
     $(d).find('message').each(function(){
        //But it never gets to here in IE
        var $msg = $(this);
        var type = $msg.attr("type");
        var message = $msg.text();
        switch (type) {
          case "HeaderMessage":
             $("#HeaderMessageDiv").html(message);
          break;
          case "FooterMessage":
             $("#footermessagecell").html(message);
          break;
        }
      });
  },
  dataType: 'xml'
});
```

Try telling jQuery what dataType its getting so that it uses the correct methods to process your request .

Answer (score 1):

I also had an same problem while importing email contacts. I was able to import contacts and display in all the browsers except in IE, as `.find()` was not working.

So, I assigned `"text/xml"` to `response.contentType`.

i.e. `response.contentType = "text/xml"` and it worked.

earlier it was `"text/html"`

Comment: Where to put response.contentType = "text/xml"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I am developing an application which is web-based, but I need it to deploy it offline, inside a CD. I found solution in this page which is the same solution you can se above http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests
and the code is very simple:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "data.xml",
   dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
   success: function(data){
     var xml;
     if (typeof data == "string") {
       xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
       xml.async = false;
       xml.loadXML(data);
     } else {
       xml = data;
     }
     // write here your XML processing logic for the document object... 
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem...

Resolved with this :

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp

```
if (window.DOMParser)
  {
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
  }
else // Internet Explorer
  {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async="false";
  xmlDoc.loadXML(text); 
  }
```

use it to transform your var to xml object...

Answer (score 0):

**It's working fine!!! Try this,**

Chrome/Firefox:

```
xml.children[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML;
```

IE8+/Safari:

```
xml.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].textContent;
```

IE8:

```
xml.documentElement.childNodes[1].text;
```

Sample code here,

```
var xml = $.parseXML(XMLDOC); 

Var xmlNodeValue = ""; 

if(userAgent.match("msie 8.0")){

xmlNodeValue = xml.children[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML;

}else{ // IE8+

xmlNodeValue = xml.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].textContent; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is generated by a PHP script you can do

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    echo '<myxml></myxml>';
?>
```

Then the find method works on every browser