# Why is IE8 on XP not properly reading from XML using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer

Given this XML in data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <bar>100</bar>
</data>
```

I want to display the content from the "bar" element using the following code in test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.get('data.xml', function(xml) {
    var foo = $(xml).find('bar').text();
    document.write("<span>foo: [" + foo + "]</span>");
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output in webkit based browsers:

```
foo: [100]
```

The output in IE8 on XP:

```
foo: []
```

Why do webkit browsers read the element's content correctly while IE8 interprets it as an empty string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[jQuery .find() doesn't return data in IE but does in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562283/jquery-find-doesnt-return-data-in-ie-but-does-in-firefox-and-chrome)

This looks to be very much the same problem. Some highlights:

*"If you get messages.xml as the wrong mime type, Internet Explorer won't parse it as XML."*

*"You need to change the server to send "text/xml" for the content type."*

Due credit to [Matthew Crumley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2214/matthew-crumley).

**And from jQuery [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests):**

*"if you specify the $.ajax dataType option to be "xml", make sure your server sends content with the "text/xml" MIME type. Sending the wrong MIME type will prohibit jQuery from correctly managing the data returned in the response"*

*"use the dataType parameter to load the xml file as text, and parse the returned data within the succes function"*

Comment: +1 Nice one. Found this thread and your answer fixed my issue. Thanks.