# IE8 not reading my XML properly with jQuery/jsonp

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm using a jsonp call (jQuery.getJSON), data returned is an XML.
I can read it nicely in FF & IE9, but it is not working on IE8.

I can not use the dataType solution suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815673/why-is-ie8-on-xp-not-properly-reading-from-xml-using-jquery) since I'm using a jsonp call. In the callback I parse the XML

```
$(xml).find("title").text()
```

Works fine with FF and IE9, fails with IE8.
What can I do ?
PS: using jQuery1.4

Comment: fails How? with a FAIL message in the IE? some other way?

Comment: nothing, no message. If I alert the result it is simply empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are using getJSON, which "Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.", and return XML-encoded data ?
I think there is your problem.

Try to use jQuery.get instead with dataType 'xml', but it should work without:
    jQuery.get( url, [ data ], [ success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ], [ dataType ] )

[jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)
[jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: yes indeed I'm using getJSON. the server returns a json encoded data thus dataType=json, however the content of that data is an XML which I need to query. I will try you idea and report back.

Comment: did try your option using $.ajax call... did not work better.

Comment: If i understand well, your xml contains a <title> ?
Maybe IE8 don't support this tag.

Comment: I had a problem yesterday with jQuery('<span class="title">') on IE8.


I switched it to jQuery('<span>', {'class':'title'}).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that IE8 has the title tag reserved for the HTML document. Attempts to use it in XML data fails. I suggest an easy hack that I just used on a project where the title tag name was replaced with 'titlex' This will defeat ie8 and allow you to retrieve title elements in a XML file such as a RSS feed.

```
xml = xml.replace(/title/g, 'titlex'); //hack for ie8
var title = $(this).find('titlex').text(); //success!
```