# Having trouble with jQuery selectors and IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I have the following code working perfeclty in FireFox, but it won't work at all on IE6:

```
$("[name=servicos\\[\\]]").each( function() {
  this.checked = false;
  alert(this.name);
 }
);

$.getJSON("check_servicos.php?id=" + id, 
 function(data) {    
  $.each(data, 
   function(key, val) {
    alert($("#" + key).attr("id"));
    if(val > 0) $("#" + key).attr("checked", "checked");
   }
  )
 } 
);
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm missing, other than a way to forcefully upgrade all browsers at my job?

Comment: Could you post the css/html elements that you are trying to select?

Comment: I assume it is the first part that does not work (*not the getJSON*). Do you get error message ? wrong names ? `try alert($("[name=servicos\\[\\]]").length);`

Comment: All the elements are checkboxes, and if IE6 can give me error messages, I would like to know how, please.

Answer (score 0):

Check that check_servicos.php is setting the correct content-type for JSON (correct content-type is discussed here: [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type)).

I had a similar problem when trying to read XML and setting the content-type to "text/xml" solved my issue.  I found the solution to my problem here: [jQuery .find() doesn't return data in IE but does in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562283/jquery-find-doesnt-return-data-in-ie-but-does-in-firefox-and-chrome).

Comment: That part worked fine on FireFox. On IE, something keeps the whole function from working.
 Even something as simple as alert("This is a test") inside the function isn't being called on IE6.

Comment: Just confirmed that setting the correct content type doesn't work. 
 The only thing like it I saw before was when my javascript had an error and FF would tell me the function I was trying to call didn't exists.