# return xml in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, types, return

My problem is that I want to return an xml file from server back to client and parsing it using ajax function of jquery. This is the code:

Client:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){          
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "search.php",  
        data: "whatever",
        dataType: "xml",
        async: false,
        success: function(xml){
            var data = $('doctor',xml).text();
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Server(php file),

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
echo "<tables>";
echo "<doctor>Someone</doctor>";
echo "</tables>";
```

I have a blank alert and I do not know why??

---

ok I found it. my php file was in this form

```
//some code
include("other.php");
//some other code
```

where the other.php file was the file I posted above. I cut/paste the header so the final php file would be

```
//some code
header('Content-type: text/xml');
include("other.php");
//some other code
```

and other.php

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
echo "<tables>";
echo "<doctor>Someone</doctor>";
echo "</tables>";
```

now it works perfect. Thanks for your quick replies!

Comment: Does $(xml).find("doctor") work?

Answer (score 3):

This is working fine

**Post.php file**

```
if($_GET['id']!=""){    
    $array = array('satyam'  => 'satyam',
                   'class'   => 'B.TECH',
                   'company' => 'Ranosys');
}   

$new ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><data>';
foreach($array as $key => $values){ 
    $new .= "<$key>$values</$key>";
}
echo $new.'</data>';

=================

function load_data(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "post.php",
        async: false, // stop browser for another activity
        data: "id=satyam",
        // dataType :'xml',
        error: function(e, b, error) { 
            for(var i in e){
              // alert(i);
            }
            alert(e.respone);
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            //alert($response);
            var data = $(msg).find("satyam").text();
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `var data = $(xml).find('doctor').text()`

In your example, 'xml' is not a jQuery object.

Comment: This won't work in IE per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562283/jquery-find-doesnt-return-data-in-ie-but-does-in-firefox-and-chrome

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse this XML (I really don't understand why , but...), you can do it by do:

```
$(xml).find('doctor').text();
```

Bye. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your function to be:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){       
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "search.php",  
        data: "whatever",
        dataType: "xml",
        async: false,
        success: function(xml){

            var xmlDoc;

            if (window.DOMParser) {
                parser = new DOMParser();
                xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
            }
            else {// Internet Explorer
                xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async = "false";
                xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
            }
            var $response = $(xmlDoc);
            var data = $response.find("doctor").text()

            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The reason for the **if (window.DOMParser) {** is that you'll have an issue with IE doing the parsing.

Comment: not working at all. i run the application on firefox 4. i tried IE9 but it doesn't show the alert at all.