# Using AJAX to display contents of an XML file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Our professor didn't exactly spend too much time explaining AJAX and wants us to display the contents of an XML file into a scrollable text area on the website we create. This is what I've made so far, but nothing is showing up in the div area that I'm trying to load the XML fie to... Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlDoc;
    function loadFunction() {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

        xmlDoc.async = false;
        xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = loadXML;

        xmlDoc.load("PartialRates.xml");
    }

    function loadXML() {
        if (xmlDoc.readyState == 4) {

            var item = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");

            //use the 'item' to populate the HTML tags.   

        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="banner.png" id="worldwidebanner" />
    <form id="login" class="login">
        <input type="text" name="email" />
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <input type="text" name="password" />
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <button type="button">Login</button>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <a href="">Forgot My Password</a>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <a href="">Create New Account</a>
    </form>
    <table>
        <tr style="background-color: #404040">
            <td width="103px" style="border: 1px solid #8ad0f2;">Home</td>
            <td width="103px" style="border: 1px solid #8ad0f2">How to Call</td>
            <td width="103px" style="border: 1px solid #8ad0f2">Buy Credit</td>
            <td width="103px" style="border: 1px solid #8ad0f2">Rates</td>
            <td width="103px" style="border: 1px solid #8ad0f2">Help Center</td>
            <td width="103px" style="border: 1px solid #8ad0f2">Contact Us</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #BFBFBF">
            <td colspan="2">Our Promise</td>
            <td colspan="2">Calling Rates</td>
            <td colspan="2">How It Works</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #736108">
            <td colspan="2">+ No Hidden Charges<br />
                + PINLess Dialing<br />
                + Balance Never Expires<br />
                + Munite Rounding<br />
                + 100% Quality Guarantee<br />
            </td>
            <td colspan="2"><div style="height: 75px" >
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">loadXML;</script>
                            </div>
            <br />Click Here for More Rates</td>
            <td colspan="2"><p>+ Sign Up<br />
                            + Buy credit and pay with any major
                            credit, debit card or PayPal<br />
                            + Dial the access number and call your 
                              destination.<br /></p>                                
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></td>
            <td colspan="2"><a href="terms.html">Terms and Conditions</a></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the XML file we are supposed to be displaying

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PartialRates>
<partialRates rate1="Argentina 1.6 cents" rate2="Brazil 2.4 cents" rate3="China 2.8     cents" rate4="India 3.5 cents" rate5="Russia 2.3 cents"></partialRates>
</PartialRates>
```

Comment: Table-based layouts? Yuck.

Comment: I would suggest switching to jQuery AJAX for easier methods and cross-browser friendly websites.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of the problem? Ideally just the javascript and html elements that are nessecary.

Answer (score 1):

See the tutorial from this page: **http://coursesweb.net/ajax/ajax-xml** , it explains how to get data from XML in JavaScript /Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Using [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you could set the `dataType` to XML and parse it easily

```
$(xml).find('partialrates').text();
```

**[See the related jQuery webpage](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [view an example using jQuery AJAX with XML here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052092/return-xml-in-jquery-ajax)**.