# grouping XML elements and displaying using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, xml

I have an XML whose elements i need to group and display using javascript.
How can I parse the xml so that the final output would be the count of the distinct elements. i.e.

The XMlstring

```
 txt = txt + "<FileList>";
            txt = txt + "<File>";
            txt = txt + "<FileID>1234</FileID>";
            txt = txt + "<FileType>image</FileType>";
            txt = txt + "<FileDateTime>201112345</FileDateTime>";
            txt = txt + "<FileTitle>something1</FileTitle>";
            txt = txt + "<FileSize>123</FileSize>";
            txt = txt + "</File>";
            txt = txt + "<File>";
            txt = txt + "<FileID>1209</FileID>";
            txt = txt + "<FileType>image</FileType>";
            txt = txt + "<FileDateTime>201167890</FileDateTime>";
            txt = txt + "<FileTitle>something1</FileTitle>";
            txt = txt + "<FileSize>123</FileSize>";
            txt = txt + "</File>";
            txt = txt + "</FileList>";
```

Html I want to display

```
  201112345 (1)
  201167890 (1)
```

Any Help would be appreciated,

Thanks, bhat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery so you can use that to give you easy access to your XML's DOM.

Just instantiate a jQuery wrapper for your XML in the usual manner:

```
var $xml = $(txt);
```

Then, [find](http://api.jquery.com/find) all the `<FileDateTime>` children and summarize their content in an object:

```
var summary = { };
$xml.find('FileDateTime').each(function() {
    // Get the element's content as text.
    var dt = $.trim($(this).text());

    // And update the summary
    if(!summary.hasOwnProperty(dt))
        summary[dt] = 0;
    ++summary[dt];
});
```

Then you have your summary data in `summary`.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gKgyr/

---

**UPDATE**: Based on [this question about XML parsing in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562283/jquery-find-doesnt-return-data-in-ie-but-does-in-firefox-and-chrome), I think using [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) will help with IE:

```
var $xml = $($.parseXML(txt));
```

I can't check right now though but here's a live version of this one: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gKgyr/12/

Comment: thanks works like a charm in chrome and firefox...but IE dosent show anything...is there a workaround for this?...thanks this was great help.

Comment: @Bhat: Have a look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562283/jquery-find-doesnt-return-data-in-ie-but-does-in-firefox-and-chrome), sounds just like the IE problem you're having. And maybe try [this version of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gKgyr/12/) in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Does not work with Internet Explorer. Will add support for that in a bit.

A simple, unoptimized implementation without jQuery;

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
var dates = xmlDoc.evaluate("/FileList/File/FileDateTime/text()", xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

var result,
  map = {},
  summary = "";

while (result = dates.iterateNext()) {
  var date = result.nodeValue.trim();
  map[date] = map[date] ? ++map[date] : 1;
}

for(var key in map)
  summary += key + "&nbsp;(" + map[key] + ")<br />";

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = summary;
```

Edit: With Internet Explorer support, it became a mess. I would use jQuery if possible.

```
// Adding trim support to Internet Explorer ...
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}

var xpath = "/FileList/File/FileDateTime/text()",
  map = {},
  summary = "";

if (window.DOMParser) {
  var parser=new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
  var dates = xmlDoc.evaluate("/FileList/File/FileDateTime/text()", xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

  var node;
  while (node = dates.iterateNext()) {
    var date = node.nodeValue.trim();
    map[date] = map[date] ? ++map[date] : 1;
  }
} else {
  // Internet Explorer
  var xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async="false";
  xmlDoc.loadXML(txt); 
  var dates = xmlDoc.selectNodes(xpath);

  for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    var date = dates[i].nodeValue.trim();
    map[date] = map[date] ? ++map[date] : 1;
  }
}

for(var key in map)
  summary += key + "&nbsp;(" + map[key] + ")<br />";

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = summary;
```