# Jquery.find() returns null in ie, but not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to code a jquery slider. I have a html code which looks like this. I had earlier posted a simpler version of code so that the question doesnt seem too long. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. Here is the actual code

```
<div class="allItems">  
    <div class="echItm">
        <h4>asdddddddd </h4>
        <span class="mImg">/web/images/promotionSlideShowImages/kc1g358wvv.jpg</span>
         <span class="tImg">/web/images/promotionSlideShowThumbnailsNew/kc1g358wvv.gif</span>
    </div>

     <div class="echItm">
        <h4>dddddddddd </h4>
        <span class="mImg">/web/images/promotionSlideShowImages/ptvrbfpnkd.jpg</span>
         <span class="tImg">/web/images/promotionSlideShowThumbnailsNew/ptvrbfpnkd.gif</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

When I try to do a find using

```
    var imagesArray=$('.allItems').find('.echItm');
    for(var i=0;i<imagesArray.length;i++){
    var thisElement=imagesArray[i];
    alert($(thisElement).html());
}
```

IE returns null, whereas firefox, chrome return the required html. Can someone guide me what am I doing wrong?  I'm using Jquery 1.4.2 and testing this on IE8. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like there might be a solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562283/jquery-find-doesnt-return-data-in-ie-but-does-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: Which IE version were you using? I've [ran your code](http://jsfiddle.net/7DLex/) on IE7 with no problem.

Comment: It seems like this might be the same issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562283/jquery-find-doesnt-return-data-in-ie-but-does-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: This is got more to do with XML responses, while my data is pure html code. I am not doing any ajax hit to get the above mentioned html.

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound I am using IE8

Comment: @Maxim Dsouza. I've [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/7DLex/3/) the code base on your update, ran it on IE8 and I was able to get the innerHTML for each div with class echItm. Maybe, you've missed parts of your code that causes the problem. Have you debug using [IE Developer Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359)? It's handy in checking IE-specific issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`testElement` is already a `jQuery` object so you don't have to wrap it in `$()`. Try this

```
var testElement=$('.echItm').find('h4');
alert(testElement.html());
```

Comment: Tried that... IE still returns null, whereas firefox works fine with this code as well...

Comment: Can you check the source in IE that is rendered on the page. I think the mark up may not be well formed so this issue is coming in IE which is not good with bad markup.

Comment: I have edited the question. I also checked the mark up in IE, it is well formed