# jQuery find() does work on Chrome and Firefox but not IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, xml-parsing

this is the response I get from a web service for a submitted Url.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 20 May 2012 15:35:52 GMT
Connection: close

841
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<doi_records>
  <doi_record owner="10.1016" timestamp="2012-04-21 12:08:25">
    <crossref>
      <journal>
        <journal_metadata language="en">
          <full_title>Procedia - Social and Behavioral Sciences</full_title>
          <abbrev_title>Procedia - Social and Behavioral Sciences</abbrev_title>
          <issn media_type="print">18770428</issn>
        </journal_metadata>
        <journal_issue>
          <publication_date media_type="print">
            <month>1</month>
            <year>2011</year>
          </publication_date>
          <journal_volume>
            <volume>15</volume>
          </journal_volume>
          <special_numbering>C</special_numbering>
        </journal_issue>
        <journal_article publication_type="full_text">
          <titles>
            <title>The effect of teaching the cognitive and meta-cognitive strategies (self-instruction procedure) on verbal math problem-solving performance of primary school students with verbal problem- solving difficulties</title>
          </titles>
          <contributors>
            <person_name contributor_role="author" sequence="first">
              <given_name>Narges</given_name>
              <surname>Babakhani</surname>
            </person_name>
          </contributors>
          <publication_date media_type="print">
            <month>1</month>
            <year>2011</year>
          </publication_date>
          <pages>
            <first_page>563</first_page>
            <last_page>570</last_page>
          </pages>
          <publisher_item>
            <item_number item_number_type="sequence-number">S1877042811003211</item_number>
            <identifier id_type="pii">S1877042811003211</identifier>
          </publisher_item>
          <doi_data>
            <doi>10.1016/j.sbspro.2011.03.142</doi>
            <resource>http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S1877042811003211</resource>
          </doi_data>
        </journal_article>
      </journal>
    </crossref>
  </doi_record>
</doi_records>
0
```

user inputs a inputs a variable is a form and clicks on a `<button>`, ajax call triggers and gets above data. then depending on the returned xml appropriate action should be done.
this is what I am doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
if ($('input:text[name=ident]').val() !=  "")
{
    $.post("<?php echo site_url('con/met/') ?>",
    {doi:$('input:text[name=ident]').val()}, 
    function(responseText){ parseXmlDoi(responseText)},  
    "html"
);
...
}
</script>
```

and here is my parseXmlDoi function:

```
function parseXmlDoi(xml)
{

    $('#debug').fadeIn();
    $('#debug').html('');

    if ($(xml).find('error').text())
    {
        $('#debug').html('<div dir="rtl" class=\"message warning\"><p>error</p></div>');
    }
    else if ($(xml).find('book').text())
    {
        $('#debug').html('<div dir="rtl" class=\"message info\"><p>this is a book</p></div>');
    }
    else if ($(xml).find('journal').text())
    {

        // do some stuff

    }
    else
    {
         $('#debug').html('<div dir="rtl" class=\"message error\"><p> something is wrong</p></div>');

    }
}
```

the problem: in Chrome and Firefox based on given above Xml, it works and it executes `// do some stuff` but at IE it says `something is wrong` it means that the `find()` is not working.

Comment: Off-topic, but: Best not to constantly call `$()` to re-parse the same XML. Call it *once* and then reuse the result. `var $xml = $(xml);`...

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562283/jquery-find-doesnt-return-data-in-ie-but-does-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: @pna: We can see the content type in what John posted. `text/xml` is still recognized, even though `application/xml` is preferred. But moreover, he's overriding default handling.

Answer (score 1):

You're explicitly telling jQuery to treat the response as HTML rather than XML, so what you get back is a string. Then you call `$()` on that string, which tells it to parse it *as HTML*, not as XML.

I can't see any reason for overriding the default processing, but I suspect it may be the issue, as IE doesn't much like HTML tags it doesn't know.

Try this instead:

```
$.post(
    "<?php echo site_url('con/met/') ?>",
    {doi:$('input:text[name=ident]').val()},
    parseXmlDoi,
    "xml" // Or leave this off, your content type should trigger XML handling
);
```

...and change the beginning of `parseXmlDoi` to:

```
function parseXmlDoi(xmlDoc)
{
    var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

    // ...now, use $xml.find...//
}
```

By telling jQuery to treat the response as XML, you'll get a parsed XML document passed into your success function. Then we use `$()` to wrap that XML document in a jQuery instance so you can use `find` on it.

Answer (score 0):

ok I got the answer:

I managed to get the exact xml from the `url` in the Ajax `POST`so the response turned to be the same except the `header` information.

and edited my Ajax call to this:

```
$.ajax({
 url:"<?php echo site_url('con/met/') ?>",
 type:"POST",
 data:{doi : $('input:text[name=ident]').val()},
 dataType: "html", //this should be html because the php page uses echo to give data back
 success: function(data)
 {
     var xml;
     if (jQuery.browser.msie) { //for IE
       xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
       xml.async = false;
       xml.loadXML(data);
     } else { //for non IE
       xml = data;
     }
     parseXmlDoi(xml);
   }   
});
```

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, and browser-sniffing should be avoided whenever possible. What happened when you tried my solution (or didn't you try it)?