# Ajax find does not work with Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, internet-explorer

I have the following code snippet which does not work in Internet Explorer, from the Web Tools (F12) it doesn't show any error on the console, it's like for IE the XML that I retrieve through the get is empty. Any hint?

```
$.get('http://x.x.x./xxx.aspx?param=' + par, function(data) {
    $(data).find('item').each(function(){
        //for some reason IE never enter this each cycle
        alert("that alert works with Chrome and Firefox but not with IE...")
    }
}
```

EDIT: Just so you know this code snippet is running on an ASPX page inside SharePoint WSS3. IE starts in IE10 Compatibility View with IE 5 Quirks as Document Mode. Also I am using Jquery 1.9.0.

Comment: Put `console.log(data);` as the 1st line inside the `get` callback and see what's returned.

Comment: I just checked it, as I expected the XML is returned, also I am using Jquery 1.9.0.

Comment: Does 'parseXML(data)' work?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562283/jquery-find-doesnt-return-data-in-ie-but-does-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: The XML contains CDATA now that you mention it, I'll give a try with the parseXML to see what it returns.